# Manipulate form's data result

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to change the result of my form's data before submitting but I am struggling with my script

My HTML

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr class="row_1">
            <td>
                <input name="flavour_1" type="text"><br>
                <input name="flavour_2" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="taste_1" type="text"><br>
                <input name="taste_2" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row_2">
            <td>
                <input name="flavour_1" type="text"><br>
                <input name="flavour_2" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="taste_1" type="text"><br>
                <input name="taste_2" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" id="serForm">Serialize Form </button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#serForm").on('click', function() {

    var db = $("form").serializeArray();

    for (var m = 0; m < db.length; m++) {
        var e = db[m],
            name = e.name,
            value = e.value;
        var parts = name.split(/_(?=\d+$)/);
        if (parts.length === 2) {
            name[parts[0]] = name[parts[0]] || [];
            name[parts[0]][parts[1] - 1] = e;
            delete e;
        }
    }
})
```

I am trying to get a result like or similar to this.

```
"flavour": [{"row_1_flavour_1_value", "row_1_flavour_2_value"},{"row_2_flavour_1_value", "row_2_flavour_2_value"}],
"taste": [{"row_1_taste_1_value", "row_1_taste_2_value"},{"row_2_taste_1_value", "row__taste_2_value"}]
```

**Note**

There is a possibility of having multiple rows (not only 2) and they are not named **row_n** the name is just for example purpose

Comment: I'm only speculating but I'm assuming further down the line you care about which flavor belongs to which taste and as far as I know you cannot rely on the fact that `flavour[0]` belongs to `taste[0]` if posting them as individual arrays. It might be better to post them as they are grouped, eg: `array[[{flavour: flavour_1, taste: taste_01},{flavour: flavour_2, taste: taste_02}], [{flavour: flavour_1, taste: taste_01},{flavour: flavour_2, taste: taste_02}]]` etc... that way each row has the data grouped as expected. Let the backend map the data itself which ever way it needs.

Comment: In regards to the above comment see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241115/how-to-serialize-table-row-to-json-object

Comment: @Fran the motive behind my format is that I would like to save them in a database as 1 record.. flavour will go in flavour table as [a,b] if 1 row and [a,b][x,y] if 2 rows and so on

Comment: That is not the UI's problem though :)  Let each layer worry about their own affairs. If you want the UI to display the data one way but save it in the database differently then don't ask the UI to give you the data in the format you want but instead post the data to the server and let the receiver worry about how to map the data to different formats, etc.. Otherwise you are creating a very tight logical coupling between the layers where one layer knows too much about the inner working of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the use of [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and finally [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Code:

```js
$('#serForm').on('click', function () {
  var db = $('form').serializeArray(),
      getFormRowValues = (arr, str, numPerRow) => arr
        .filter(el => new RegExp(str).test(el.name))
        .map(el => el.value)
        .reduce((a, c, i) => ((a[i / numPerRow | 0] = a[i / numPerRow | 0] || []).push(c), a), []),
      result = {
        flavour: getFormRowValues(db, 'flavour', 2),
        taste: getFormRowValues(db, 'taste', 2)
      };

  console.log(result);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr class="row_1">
      <td>
        <input name="flavour_1" value="flavour_1_value" type="text"><br>
        <input name="flavour_2" value="flavour_2_value" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="taste_1" value="taste_1_value" type="text"><br>
        <input name="taste_2" value="taste_2_value" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_2">
      <td>
        <input name="flavour_1" value="flavour_1_value" type="text"><br>
        <input name="flavour_2" value="flavour_2_value" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="taste_1" value="taste_1_value" type="text"><br>
        <input name="taste_2" value="taste_2_value" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="serForm">Serialize Form </button>
</form>
```

Comment: the problem with this is I can't identify the order of "row", I want it to be "flavour" : {[a,b],[x,y]} or [[a,b][x,y]] so I know how many rows they are and where is where

Comment: Check now that the array of objects `result.flavour` and `result.taste` has been sorted by the `name` property

Comment: I noticed you hardcoding the names of inputs... is there a way to just pull it from the db var? the form will have more than flavour and taste

Comment: [{"row_1_flavour_1_value", "row_1_flavour_2_value"},{"row_2_flavour_1_value", "row_2_flavour_2_value"}]  are not valid objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152759/discussion-between-yosvel-quintero-and-jonathan).

Answer (score 1):

This solutions isn't as index heavy but I think it a bit more simple.

```js
$("#serForm").on('click', function() {
    var flavourArr = getInputValuesByName('flavour');
    var tasteArr = getInputValuesByName('taste'); 

    console.log(flavourArr);
    console.log(tasteArr);
})

function getInputValuesByName(name){
    var arr = [];
    $('form input[name*="' + name + '"]').each(function(k,v){ 
        var parentClass = $(v).closest('tr').attr('class');
        
        arr.push(parentClass + "_" + $(v).val()); 
    });

    return arr;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <table>
            <tr class="row_1">
            <td>
                <input name="flavour_1" value="flavour_1_value" type="text"><br>
                <input name="flavour_2" value="flavour_2_value" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="taste_1" value="taste_1_value" type="text"><br>
                <input name="taste_2" value="taste_2_value" type="text">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row_2">
            <td>
                <input name="flavour_1" value="flavour_1_value" type="text"><br>
                <input name="flavour_2" value="flavour_2_value" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="taste_1" value="taste_1_value" type="text"><br>
                <input name="taste_2" value="taste_2_value" type="text">
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" id="serForm">Serialize Form </button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```